Onde eu posso encontrar um Bancos de Dados de Redações Corrigidas em Português?
Estou procurando um banco de dados de redações que pode ser do ENEM, concursos, vestibulares, universidades, etc, porém, devem ter sido corrigidas em português por humanos. Alguém sabe onde eu poderia encontrar?

Acho que concursos etc, não constituem "um libro aberto" acessível ao  público  geral. Seria um vexame para os concursantes/participantes...

Vexame não é pois existem programas que treinaram I.A de correção de redações com mais de 100 mil redações corrigidas por humanos, então em algum lugar deve ter, só estou procurando onde está

Quem disse que esses textos ficam com as empresas de IA? E em todo caso, essas empresas não daram os texto ao primeiro passante.

Esta pergunta no SO seria considerada off-topic por ser uma pedido de recursos, mas no pt.se aceitamos pedidos de recursos -embora, haja uma disucussão se este tipo de perguntas é mais adequado para o meta ou para o site principal. Qualquer das maneiras vou votar para a perguntar ficar aqui.

O que estás a pedir é um dos géneros de recursos mais difíceis de encontrar, pois dados que foram manualmente revisados por humanos são geralmente escassos. Mas se pesquisares no google por dataset+redação+enem+corrigido vais encontrar muitos modelos, já para encontrar um dataset que tenha a garantia da correcção ou o par com erro/corrigido vai ser bastante mais difícil - mas deve ser possivel principalmente com dataset mais pequeno.

Este trabalho aqui dá uma ideia no contexto do automatic-grading https://www.researchgate.net/publication/355261259_Essay-BR_a_Brazilian_Corpus_of_Essays também tem uma visão geral do estado dos datasets publicamente disponiveis. Esta monografia recente https://josemayer.dev/mac0499/docs/monografia.pdf também parece ir para o mesmo lado...

Este tipo de pergunta é considerado on-topic aqui? Estou perguntando porque no JP.SE nós encerramos esse tipo de perguntas como off-topic.

@bad_coder muito obrigado pelos artigos, estava querendo ler algo assim, com certeza irei ler os dois! Algumas pessoas que conversei sobre o assunto me deram a ideia da própria IA corrigir as redações e elas mesmas se basearem nas redações que elas criaram para corrigir novas feitas por humanos, será que isso seria viável também?

@MayconSilva isso é uma perguta de computação teórica na área da inteligência artifical e processamento de linguagens naturais. Deve ser colocada no https://ai.stackexchange.com/

O Uol tem um banco de redações. Lá é dito que "a avaliação foi feita por uma equipe de professores".
Link: https://educacao.uol.com.br/bancoderedacoes/.

Engraçado, você descubriu um desses bancos e ninguém deu um voto positivo? Pois, eu sim. +1

@Lambie descobriu, Pois eu, sim

@Lambie Na verdade, eu recebi alguns votos negativos. Por alguma razão, alguns usuários não ficaram satisfeitos.

Pois é, tem "negativistas" por aí. :) Sobre tudo, uns recém-chegados.  Houve um momento que eu tive votos negativos em série. Mas geralmente o sistema termina por corrigir isso.

Obrigado pela resposta @Pedro ! +1 aqui. Eu já tinha visto esse banco deles, só não consegui encontrar como acessar essas redações, se há alguma API ou se eu deveria fazer um web scraping no site para coletar esses dados. Por outro lado, há esse repositório no GitHub também que tem por volta de 2500 redações que não sei se está sendo atualizado, é pouco, mas já ajuda, ainda estou na procura, mas é realmente difícil encontrar...
